VSCode doesn't save files when opened from zip packs
For my work I need to edit various files that are packaged in a .zip file. Whenever I need to edit them, I just open the .zip file (without unpacking) in Total Commander and open the file I want to edit in VSCode.
Not always, but many times the following happens:
TC asks if I want to overwrite the file - this is when I know it surely will be messed up.
If I overwrite, VSC opens the file, I edit it, but almost immediately after opening, the filename will be striked through, as if it is deleted. (This sometimes also happens even without TC asking of the overwriting). Even if I save it, the file will not actually be edited and all my changes will be gone.
Other times, after editing the file and closing VSC, TC will ask me if I want to re-pack the files, which is when I know it will be saved as I want that.
I think this is an issue with how TC unzips the files into a temp folder and how VSC handles those. My question mainly is if there's a setting/option in either TC or VSC to make my workflow bette, not having to edit a file many times just to be able to save the changes once. I'd prefer not having to unzip the packs for this, as many times there's just one file I want to edit out of a thousand, or I can just mess up the repackaging by adding more or less back.
I have checked settings in both VSC and TC, but haven't found much that seemed to help. Maybe someone had similar issues and found a solution?
